# Android Contacts-Edit

Tags: android-contacts

In my application, i am using Intent class for adding Name,Phone number and email to contacts.
I want to edit a particular contact. how can i get the corresponding identifier for that  contact ? Please help me. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try passing the value of your contact name to this code:

```
Cursor cur = this.context.getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_URI, null, Data.DISPLAY_NAME + " like '"yourcontactname"%'", null, null);
```